# remove pivot chart label through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm total new with Excel-VBA and I'm here to ask your help! 
I have a workbook in Excel 2003 where there's a pivot table in the sheet "PivotTableSheet" from which I have created an embedded Pivot chart in sheet "ChartSheet" using this code:

```
Sub CreateChartForPivot()
   Charts.Add
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("PivotTableSheet").Range("B5:B8"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
   ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="ChartSheet"
   ActiveChart.Legend.Delete    
End Sub
```

The result works pretty fine, but I'd like to remove the labels "Drop Page Fields Here" and "Drop Series Fields Here" at the top and the right of the chart. They are just awful ;-)

Can anyone help me doing that in VBA?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to remove the labels is to do the below but then it will hide the rest of the buttons as well.

With the pivot chart selected, on the pivot toolbar, choose PivotChart>Hide PivotChart Field buttons.

If you want a VBA code, You can record a macro for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Sheets("PivotTableSheet").ShowDrillIndicators = False
```

or

```
Sheets("PivotTableSheet").DisplayFieldCaptions = False
```